# java process, executing commands does not work on windows machine

Tags: process, command, outputstream

I am executing a sbt via java process. When it is executed I want to interact with this childprocess(java). For example I want to execute "show full-classpath". That all works on MAC and is tested! but the same sourcecode does not work on Windows! Does anybody know why?
I also tried to extend the command with appending "\n", "\n\n" and "\r\n". Here is the code:

```
public Process makeProcess(String dir, String model) throws IOException {
        List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
        command.add("scala.bat");
        Process process = null;
        final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
        pb.command(command);

        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);

        process = pb.start();
        if (process == null) {
            return null;
        }
        final BufferedReader stream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                process.getInputStream(), Charset.defaultCharset()));

        OutputStream o = process.getOutputStream();

        Thread t = new Thread(new ConsoleListener(stream));
        t.start();



        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("executing....");
                o.write("show full-classpath\n".getBytes());

        o.flush();
                o.close();
        return process;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ProcessControl control = new ProcessControl();
        control.makeProcess(null,null);
    }
```

I am really confused so far, because when I run it with "cmd.exe" and "dir" as command, it works also on a windows machine..

Comment: does no body know why this is the case? tried it on ubuntu where it worked as well!

Comment: have you got to the bottom of this?
facing same issue where it is working on ubuntu but not on windows